# How to regex simple query like language

Tags: regex

I have an interesting problem that I just cannot seem to find where to start on. Imagine I have, as a complete standard:

```
field:(la blah theehe) field1:(ghgth) field2:(234) OR field:(thgt) sdfdsf dsfgf sdfg
```

String just come in from a search.

Is there a reliable way in regex to effectively "parse" that query down into something more manageable like:

```
[
   "field:(la blah theehe)",
   "field1:(ghgth)",
   "field2:(234)",
   "OR",
   "field:(thgt)",
   "sdfdsf dsfgf sdfg"
]
```

So that from there I could build a query for it, or am I thinking completely wrong with this?

Essentially all fields would be of the form `fieldName:(fieldValue)` and the `OR` between fields would be treated exactly like that, the default operator between fields being an `AND`.

For those parts that don't match the standard I would typically just treat them as normal strings.

I know this is quite a big question and even just pointers would be really good.

Comment: Why do you want to use regexes?

Comment: @utdemir it seemed like a good choice, they are quite flexible, is there a better option?

Comment: Split after every closing bracket `)` - include the `OR` operator where is happens.. that's probably the best you can do. I'm getting a feeling that you shouldn't be using regex here for a "reliable" solution.

Comment: @scrowler indeed possibly, I had this idea of "picking" the data out with regex for some reason, like using preg_split in PHP

Comment: what part exactly of that input going to change?

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: if you showed three different examples what could be different between them?

Comment: in PHP - I would explode by the closing bracket, then explode by the opening bracket to get the field name and value, then explode the field name by a space (which would only be there if you had AND or OR, trim and you should have a reasonably consistent option...

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown there could be spelling mistakes but those would be treated as normal strings in this case, i.e. anything that doesn't match the strict field of the field notation or `OR` is treated as a normal string, but apart from that 3 examples would be exactly the same

Comment: @scrowler Yes something does seem viable there, let's see if I puke something up, thanks :)

Comment: Quick example... https://eval.in/100642

Comment: @scrowler thanks! Something I can work from

Comment: @scrowler I just got another idea based off me talking about "extracting" fields, if I did regex matches for the field standard and the optional OR then I could go through those matches in sequence removing them from the original search string, that way I could build the query in order correctly and then have the rubbish left over to form in LIKE keywords

Comment: @scrowler something like `([a-z]+:\(.*\)(\s+OR)?)` which actually works, hmm more investigating needed.

Comment: @Sammie, just thought that was important to clarify ;)

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown indeed, I don't expect something to give me everything :) though I think the regex I just came up with might provide me with the answer, I use it to remove matches from the search sting and boom I should have a spelling mistake proof way of parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I reckon I have a good answer to this, anyone correct me if I am wrong. Good to know that this will be using PHP functions but the regex is the important part.

@scrowlers advice was good but what about spelling mistakes and context etc etc?

So I thought about it:- if I am able to "extract" the query parts that exactly match the field standard without spelling I could parse it. All other strings will be left behind as keywords. So I came up with a regex to express the standardization of the field syntax:

```
([a-z]+:\(.[^\)]*\)(\s+OR\s+|\s+or\s+)?)
```

Which basically searches for the field and an optional `OR` if it exists.

for every match I get in a loop I will remove that match from the original search string. This way I am able to "extract" the query for parsing. Not only that but (in PHP at least) the matches are in order they are found which also means my query won't get garbled up by running this regex.

So now this means I can run:

```
listing:(1,2) title:(vid_) or mature:(1) deleted:(0) lala:(gfg ghffd
```

Without getting the erroneous `lala` from breaking everything.

The last problem was security, I had to make sure I didn't just blindly take the fields and use them to form a query my side. To do this I replaced the `[a-z]+` in the original regex with my field list like so:

```
((field|date):\(.[^\)]*\)(\s+OR\s+|\s+or\s+)?)
```

which meant I could now run this query:

```
field:(blajh blah bla) or field:(sdfdf) sdgff sdg fd date:(12022013 TO 12062013) fiedl1:(lala) date:(2 TO 5)
```

And `fiedl1` would not come up in the matches.

I believe that solves all my problems, let me know if I am wrong.

Thanks for the help,